# How to fix "WARNING: The `useMongoClient` option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x, please remove it."

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem using my loginapp made with nodejs but i didnt understand the 'remove usemongoclient' because i already remove it ! please help

Full error :

```
WARNING: The `useMongoClient` option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x, please remove it.
    at handleUseMongoClient (C:\Users\Corentin\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:610:17)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Corentin\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:480:7)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Corentin\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:271:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Corentin\Documents\newLoginapp\models\user.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Corentin\Documents\newLoginapp\routes\users.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
(node:15100) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be
removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Server started on port 3000
(node:15100) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

This is my code : (Not full) ask for more code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tuto', { useNewUrlParser: true })

var db = mongoose.connection;

const routes = require('./routes/index');
const users = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();
```

But the backend system work good, i didnt understand ! ;'(

Comment: what does this code `var db = mongoose.connection;` ? Think is not necessary and maybe its that your error. You connect in `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tuto', { useNewUrlParser: true })`

Answer (score 4):

```
//Connect to mongoose (
mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI, {

     useNewUrlParser: true    //add it
    //useMongoClient: true //old

})
.then(() => console.log('Veri baglantisi saglandi...'))
.catch(err =>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Please provide a description to your answer to improve its quality and your thoughts on that.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove or replace

```
useMongoClient: true //remove it
```

from your database configuration file because this is not supported in current  mongoose version and just add below code in your database config file

```
useNewUrlParser: true    //add it
```

Example

```
//Connect to mongoose 
   exports.connect = () => {
  mongoose.connect(mongo.uri,{
    keepAlive: 1,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });
  return mongoose.connection;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.x mongoose no longer necessary 'useMongoClient'. 
After removing it, You have to use new parsers as follows,

1. For new URL parser, pass option

```
'useNewUrlParser: true'
```

2. For new server discovery and monitoring engine, pass option

```
' useUnifiedTopology: true '
```

final code part looks like,

```
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://localhost/tuto',
    {
        // useMongoClient: true // old parameter
        useNewUrlParser: true, // new parameters
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
);
```

hopefully it more helps for the latest mongoose versions, ex:- 5.8.9.

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs beacuase the `useMongoClient` option is no longer supports to mongoose new versions (>5.x).

solution is remove

```
useMongoClient: true //remove this code
```

and replace it with

```
useNewUrlParser: true //add this code
```

**Example**

```
mongoose.connect('<<your uri>>', {
// useMongoClient: true
useNewUrlParser: true
```

});